# Example of $H^n(X,R)$ not equal to $Hom(H_n(X,R),R)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

The universal coefficient theorem shows that under suitable assumptions, the cohomology groups with coefficients in $R$ are simply the morphisms between the homology groups and $R$.

In general, though, the standard morphism $m:H^n(X,R)\to Hom_R(H_n(X,R),R)$ is only surjective, not injective.

Is there a standard, simple, illustrative example of the failure of $m$ to be one to one?

In particular, I'm looking for an example with $R$ a PID (and not too complicated), and $X$ a CW/cell complex.

Thanks!

**Update**: Sorry to all, I meant "ring". I don't know why I wrote "group" yesterday... Too little coffee I guess!

Comment: Why are there two $G$'s in the $Hom$ both in the title and the body of the question)? When you replace the first $G$ with $\Bbb Z$ in the title, then this is an isomorphism, because $H_0$ is free abelian  group, and thus the $Ext^1$ vanishes.

Comment: So by writing $G$ you mean homomorphisms over the group ring I assume?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat I think it is rude to question a question which is understandable, just because you have an answer to an easy special case.

Comment: @Dan You seem to suggest that my question was designed merely as a way to show off, when in reality I was trying to rule out either a confusion or a typo: the universal coefficient theorem, at least the one I know, relates homology with coefficients in a *PID* to cohomology with coefficients in a module over said PID. How is suggesting that there may be a $\Bbb Z$ (or any other PID for that matter) rather than a $G$ for the coefficients of homology a rude question when the question doesn't seem to make sense without it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me stick to the case that everything has coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. Then universal coefficients says that the sequence

$$0 \to \text{Ext}^1(H_{n-1}(X), \mathbb{Z}) \to H^n(X) \to \text{Hom}(H_n(X), \mathbb{Z}) \to 0$$

is exact, and so the natural morphism $H^n(X) \to \text{Hom}(H_n(X), \mathbb{Z})$ is an isomorphism iff

$$\text{Ext}^1(H_{n-1}(X), \mathbb{Z}) = 0.$$

If $H_{n-1}(X)$ is finitely generated then $\text{Ext}^1(H_{n-1}(X), \mathbb{Z})$ is noncanonically isomorphic to the torsion subgroup of $H_{n-1}(X)$ (exercise), so this is true iff $H_{n-1}(X)$ is torsion-free.

Hence to find the simplest counterexample we should look at the simplest example of a space with torsion in its homology. Let's take $X = \mathbb{RP}^2$, so that $H_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $H_2(X) = 0$ (because $X$ is not orientable). Then $\text{Hom}(H_2(X), \mathbb{Z}) = 0$, but

$$H^2(X) = \text{Ext}^1(H_1(X), \mathbb{Z}) = \text{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}_2, \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}_2.$$

Comment: There's really no reason to be afraid of the full statement of universal coefficients. It's not that complicated (it's not, say, a spectral sequence), and in particular over $\mathbb{Z}$ and in the case that everything is finitely generated it leads to a straightforward description of the isomorphism class of $H^n(X)$: its torsion-free part is the same as that of $H_n(X)$, and its torsion part is the same as that of $H_{n-1}(X)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I had made a mistake in the question...could you please update?

Comment: @geodude: I think there were still a few typos in the question, so I edited them. Can you confirm that it's now correct?

Comment: Yes, thanks! It's exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

Start with any $X$ which has torsion in first homology.